# PHP - How to send values in Multiple pages Form

Tags: php, html, forms

So, I was working on a PHP Application Center (Form), and I'm stuck at something.

I have 3 pages of form and 1 sumbit page. All are in .php extention. So, I want to take the `<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>` from page one and:

`<label>About yourself (Atleast 50 Words): <span>*</span></label><br />
<textarea name="yourself" placeholder="About yourself (Atleast 50 Words)" ></textarea>` to the submit page.

I can take the values of Textarea & Textbox from page 3 to submit page through `<?php echo $_POST['somethinghere']?>`. But I can't take values from the First and second page.

Here are links to my php codes with style.css (pastebin.com):- http://pastebin.com/81vgHh5H

Comment: Use [`$_SESSION`](http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: Store them in a `$_SESSION` from page to page. - The point of this community is to show you how to figure something out on your own, not post your entire project and expect someone to do it for you. Had you been a contributor to the community it would be different but you just now signed up. We can give you the resources, but you should be doing the actual work yourself. Can you tell us what you have already tried and didn't work? Anything that shows that you tried to resolve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the Pastebin and I think I can see the problem.  You're setting the Session data on the same page that they're filling out (so you're assigning those fields to the session before they've even been filled in).  You need to do that on page 2, not page 1.  So your pattern is thus:

1. Show page 1 form.
2. User fills it out and hits submit.
3. Send user to page 2.
4. Page 2 grabs the information posted from Page 1, stores it in the session.
5. Page 2 shows the second form page.
6. User fills out page 2 and hits submit.
7. Send user to page 3.
8. Page 3 grabs the information posted from Page 2, stores it in the session.

And so on...

By the time you get to the last page, your session will contain all the information from the form and you can then process it however you need to.

Example:

Page 1:

```
<form action="page2.php">
    <input type="text" name="page1text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['page1text'] = $_POST['page1text'];
?>
<form action="page3.php">
    <input type="text" name="page2text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Page 3:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['page2text'] = $_POST['page2text'];
?>
<form action="page4.php">
    <input type="text" name="page3text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Page 4:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['page3text'] = $_POST['page3text'];
?>
<ul>
    <li>Page 1: <?php echo $_SESSION['page1text'] ?></li>
    <li>Page 2: <?php echo $_SESSION['page2text'] ?></li>
    <li>Page 3: <?php echo $_SESSION['page3text'] ?></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, page 4 winds up with access to all of the information from the previous pages.

Edit: This answer previously read: I would recommend having a model that contains all of the form's properties.  As they fill out each page, populate the model with the data the user has entered and then when they successfully complete the form you can destroy the session data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try and let you know if it works or not. I'll edit this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in session like, pass your data from page one to page two and in page two do following

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

Again, pass your data from page two to page three and in page three do following

```
$_SESSION['yourself'] = $_POST['yourself'];
```

This will set your name and yourself data in session and will be accessible from any page. Do not forget to include session_start() at the top of your page if that page uses session.

Now, you can access those session variable from submit page like,

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_SESSION['yourself'];
```